# Can I assign a string that ends with a multiple whitespace line in a bash shell variable?

Tags: bash, shell

I got a problem with storing some lines in a bash shell variable.

There is a file that contains a string like this.

```
$ vim a.txt
------we-are-in-vim------
first line
second line


-------end-of-file-------
```

This file has two empty lines that placed on the end of it.

When I cat this file, I can see that a blank is printed!

```
$ cat a.txt
first line
second line


$
```

Well. now, I can easily imagine that I can put this in a bash variable.

Let's try!

```
$ VAR=`cat a.txt`
$ echo "${VAR}"
first line
second line
$
```

Ok. I did not rap the cat command's output with double quotation! ;)

```
$ VAR="`cat a.txt`"
$ echo "${VAR}"
first line
second line
$
```

Ok. let's try with printf built-in variable assignment feature!

```
$ printf -v VAR "`cat a.txt`"
$ echo "${VAR}"
first line
second line
$
```

....Ok let's try with the mapfile command!

```
$ mapfile < a.txt VAR
$ printf '%s' "${VAR[@]}"
first line
second line


$
```

The mapfile command worked, but this is exactly the same with cat!

```
$ VAR2=`printf '%s' "${VAR[@]}"`
$ echo "${VAR2}"
first line
second line
$
```

I have already tried 'changing IFS to nothing' in bash,

But the result is exactly the same!

How can I assign the string that has two empty lines on the end of it, to a bash variable?

Comment: If you want to slurp the file in a variable, just use the proper builtin. In this case, you want to use `read`: `IFS= read -r -d '' var < a.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because that is how command-substitution in `bash` works!

See this `man bash` except under `COMMAND SUBSTITUTION`

> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command name.  There are two forms:
>
> $(command)
>
> `command`
>
> [..] Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command **with any trailing  newlines  deleted**. [..]

Comment: sorry to hear that... I should have a habit of reading the manual. :) thank you!

Comment: @이형욱: Not a problem, the `mapfile` approach seems to be the right one. Use it that way to solve your cases :)

Answer (score 2):

The usual wisdom is to append a character and remove it after:

```
$ a="`cat a.txt; echo x`"; echo "${a%x}"
first line
second line


$
```

That's a work around for the POSIX (most shells) specified variable expansion.
POSIX require that [trailing newlines should be removed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03).

> removing sequences of one or more  characters at the end of the substitution

The alternative, if reading from a file (instead of executing some command), is to do the reading directly with the shell. If the shell's `read` accepts the option `-d` (since bash 2.04):

```
$ IFS='' read -d '' VAR < a.txt
$ echo "$VAR"
```

Or read with the command `readarray` (aka `mapfile`, since bash 4.0 alpha) as you already found.